# Solutions for selecting and attaching images to models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, carrierwave

I'm trying to be lazy and would rather find an existing gem, plugin, etc. instead of writing my own implementation. The use case seems to me general enough that there may be something out there, but I can't find anything.

We're using Ruby on Rails and carrierwave to have users upload images that attach to so-called activities (which need to be curated several times a day). It turns out that users often (re-)use the same images for different activities. Instead of making the users upload the same image again all the time, I want to present them with a small gallery of images, and let them pick one to be used (or let them upload if they really want to, of course).

Is there something out there that would help me ?